# Gmail or Yahoo to send Image or greeting without an attachment?

Tags: image, gmail, imagesource, yahoo-mail

How to send images or greeting via Gmail or yahoo without an attachment by which when the receiver will open a mail it will directly show the image or greeting directly

Answer (score 0):

You can use any as long as they support html format emails.

In code you have to place base64 encoded image like `<img alt="" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAn.....SuQmCC" />`. I use http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter for encoding.